# Function calling for a financial manager in python

Tags: python

I've been working on a Financial Manager, and even though the code is not fully complete I'm trying to run it a couple of times to improve it. The financial manager is really simple. You define what type of income you have and your monthly income and the code uses predefined percentages to separate how much money you need for clothing, rent, savings, etc.

While running the code, if I answer "no" to the question, "Is this your first time using my financial manager?" the code continues with line 22. If I answer "Low Income" to the question, "What stage are you in your financial journey?" the code ends and the terminal is killed.

Can anyone please help me on how to continue with my code?

```
def low_code(budget_poor):
    groceries_poor = 0.1 * budget_poor
    emergency_poor = 0.05 * budget_poor
    clothing_poor = 0.1 * budget_poor
    rent_poor = 0.5 * budget_poor
    savings_poor = 0.25 * budget_poor
    print("\n\n***************************************************")
    print(f"\nYour monthly budget overall is ${budget_poor}.")
    print(f"Your monthly recommended budget for groceries is ${groceries_poor}")
    print(f"Your monthly recommended budget for emergencies is ${emergency_poor}")
    print(f"Your monthly recommended budget for clothing is ${clothing_poor}")
    print(f"Your monthly recommended budget for rent is ${rent_poor}")
    print(f"Your monthly recommended budget for savings is ${savings_poor}")
    return


def startup_code_for_financial_manager():

    question = input("Is this your first time using my financial manager?").lower()

    if question=="no":
        answer = input("What stage are you in your financial journey?\nJust to remind you, there are 3 levels. Low Income, Middle Class, and High Income!").lower
        def ask_question(answer):
            if answer == "low income":
                budget_poor = int(input("What is your budget every month?"))
                low_code(budget_poor)
            if answer == "middle class":
                def okay_man():
                    budget_okay = input(float("What is your budget every month?"))
                    return
                okay_man()
            if answer == "high income":
                def top_g():
                    budget_g = input(float("What is your budget every month?"))
                    return
                top_g()
        ask_question()
    else:
        #Main place for initial code launch Ex: Greetings, run code, etc.
        print("Welcome to the All Class Financial Manager!\nCreated by Kashyap Sukshavasi")
        print("\nThere are 3 stages to this financial manager.")
        print("\nFirstly, Low Income. This is if your monthly pay is below $1,500")
        print("\nSecond, Middle Class. This is if your monthly pay is between $3,000 and $10,000.")
        print("\nFinally, High Income. This is if your monthly pay is higher that $20,000.")
        ask_question()
        return

startup_code_for_financial_manager()
```

I've tried to create my functions elsewhere, and call them further down the code but that did not work out

Comment: `answer` is the method `str.lower`, it is not equal to any of the strings `"low income"`, `"middle class"`, `"high income"`. Look up how you have used `.lower` correctly 3 lines earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 37 where you call `ask_question()`, you forgot to pass in the `answer`. Your code, as you have provided, should look like this:

```py
                 budget_g = input(float("What is your budget every month?"))
                 return
             top_g()
     ask_question(answer)
 else:
     #Main place for initial code launch Ex: Greetings, run code, etc.
```

The error output suggests this is the case:

```
TypeError: startup_code_for_financial_manager.<locals>.ask_question() missing 1 required positional argument: 'answer'
```

With that said, do not include functions inside other functions unless you know exactly why you are doing it. Your code could be a lot more cleaner and less prone to errors if you moved the inlined functions to the top level indentation. Many of the returns are also unecessary.